# Take multiple value of an array in an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object with an array with different values

```
var myObj = {
            "number": 10,
            "general": "general",
            "array": [{
                "num1": 11,
                "text": "text1",
            }, {
                "num2": 1,
                "text": "text2",
            }, {
                "num3": 3,
                "text": "text3",

            } ]
        };
```

How is it possible to have a result like text1,text2,text3

I try this

```
for (i=0; i <myObj.array.length; i++) {
    a = myObj.array[i].text
    a1 += a
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map` method

```
var result = myObj.array.map(function (item) {
  return item.text;
});
```

If you need result as string, you can use `join` method:
    `result.join(',');`

Comment: You'd need a join at the end to get the OP's string.  But, +1 for map

Comment: @BarbaraLaird thanks for pointing this out, I didn't understand, that result is needed as string.

Answer (score 3):

You could push the values to an array and then join with `join(',')`

```
var myObj = {
            "number": 10,
            "general": "general",
            "array": [{
                "num1": 11,
                "text": "text1",
            }, {
                "num2": 1,
                "text": "text2",
            }, {
                "num3": 3,
                "text": "text3",

            }, ]
        };

var a1 = [];
for (i=0; i <myObj.array.length; i++) {
    a1.push(myObj.array[i].text);
}
var resultString = a1.join(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a loop. Rather, [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**join**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var myObj = {
  "number": 10,
  "general": "general",
  "array": [{
    "num1": 11,
    "text": "text1",
  }, {
    "num2": 1,
    "text": "text2",
  }, {
    "num3": 3,
    "text": "text3",

  }]
};
var mapped = myObj.array.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.text;
});

var joined = mapped.join(',');
console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an forEach-Loop:

```
myObj.array.forEach(function(entry) {
    line += entry.text;
});
```